# Azure single sign on is redirecting to microsoft account page

Tags: android, azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

I used this project to configure Single sign on by using `Microsoft Azure`.

[Github- MSAL](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-android-native-msal/blob/master/README.md#community-help-and-support)

I replaced key in mainifest file, and updated [Constaints.java](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-android-native-msal/blob/master/android-client/app/src/main/java/com/azuresample/msalandroidapp/Constants.java).

This issue is when i click on `CALL API`, it takes me to microsoft account page, and does not display the custom page, that has Facebook, Google, and Microsoft accounts links.

In Sample project `Authority` variable has following URL;

> final static String AUTHORITY =
>   "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/%s/%s";

I have updated it with this;

> final static String AUTHORITY =
>   "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient";

From console i am unable to find out the url pattern defined in the sample app.

I think if i get the correct `Authority URL`, i will be able to get the correct page.

- EDIT *
  if i don't change Authority, it gives me following error message screen.

[image]

Comment: The sample uses Azure AD B2C and MSAL, but your authority is for AAD v1, which should be using ADAL instead of MSAL. Are you trying to use B2C?

Comment: @juunas Yes i am using B2C, is there any other sample available that can fulfill my requirement. I am new to azure, and there is very little help available. I am stuck in this from tomorrow, and the irony is sample app is working fine, but as soon as i change values in `constaints.java` it takes me to Microsoft account page, and after entering credentials it gives me null token.

Comment: You should not be changing the AUTHORITY. You should only need to edit the other values to match your B2C tenant setup.

Comment: If i don;t change authority, it gives me an error message. I have added the screenshot on question. Please check it. I have also not updated the SCOPE_URL and API_URL

Comment: The screenshot has no useful info. Below that is usually some error code.

Comment: SCOPES = "https://fabrikamb2c.onmicrosoft.com/demoapi/demo.read";
API_URL = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient";

Comment: This is what i am getting, Correlation ID: "2232-34231-21312" Timestamp: "". The Client Id '51---'is not registered in tenant `mytenant.onmicrosoft.com`

Comment: @juunas : I was using the application id, instead of project id, Thanks to you for highlighting this, now its saying , The application associated with client id ``has not registered redirect URI;s